# Working with unique values at scale (for loops, apply, or plyr)

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr, apply, dplyr

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it is, it would make life oh so much more efficient.

The general problem that would be interesting to the wider SO community: for loops (and base functions like apply) are applicable for general/consistent operations, like adding X to every column or row of a data frame. I have a general/consistent operation I want to carry out, but with *unique* values for each element of the data frame.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently than subsetting my data frame for every grouping, applying the function with specific numbers relative to that grouping, then recombining? I don't care if it's a *for loop* or *apply*, but bonus points if it makes use of *plyr* functionality.

---

Here's the more specific problem I'm working on: I've got the data below. Ultimately what I want is a dataframe for time-series that has the date, and each column represents a region's relation to some benchmark.

The problem: the measure of interest for each region is different, and so is the benchmark. Here's the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

data <- data.frame(
    region = sample(c("northeast","midwest","west"), 100, replace = TRUE),
    date = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-02-01"), length=10, by = "1 day"),10),
    population = sample(50000:100000, 10, replace = T),
    skiers = sample(1:100),
    bearsfans = sample(1:100),
    dudes = sample(1:100)
)
```

and the summary frame that I'm working off:

```
data2 <- data %.%
    group_by(date, region) %.%
    summarise(skiers = sum(skiers), 
            bearsfans= sum(bearsfans), 
            dudes = sum(dudes), 
            population = sum(population)) %.%
    mutate(ppl_per_skier = population/skiers,
            ppl_per_bearsfan = population/bearsfans,
            ppl_per_dude = population/dudes) %.%
    select(date, region, ppl_per_skier, ppl_per_bearsfan , ppl_per_dude)
```

Here's the tricky part:

- For the Northeast, I only care about "ppl_per_skier", and the benchmark is 3500
- For the Midwest, I only care about "ppl_per_bearsfan", and the benchmark is 1200
- For the West, I only care about "ppl_per_dude", and the benchmark is 5000

Any of the ways I've come up with to tackle this problem involve creating subsets for each measure, but doing this at scale with hundreds of measures and different benchmarks is... not ideal. For example:

```
midwest <- data2 %.% 
            filter(region == "midwest") %.%
            select(date, region, ppl_per_bearsfan) %.%
            mutate(bmark = 1200, against_bmk = bmark/ppl_per_bearsfan-1) %.%
            select(date, against_bmk)
```

and likewise for each region, its respective measure, and its respective benchmark, then recombining them all together by date. Ultimately, I want something like this, where each region's performance against its specific benchmark and measure is laid out by date (this is fake data, of course):

```
        date midwest_againstbmk northeast_againstbmk west_againstbmk
1 2010-02-10          0.9617402            0.6008032       0.3403260
2 2010-02-11          0.5808621            0.5119942       0.7787559
3 2010-02-12          0.4828346            0.6560053       0.3747920
4 2010-02-13          0.6499841            0.7567194       0.8387461
5 2010-02-14          0.6367520            0.4564254       0.7269161
```

Is there a way to get to this sort of data and structure without having to do X number of subsets for each grouping, when I have unique measures and benchmark values for each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an obvious use case for `mapply`:

```
> mapply(function(d,y,b) {(b/d[,y])-1},
         split(data2,data2$region), 
         c('ppl_per_bearsfan','ppl_per_skier','ppl_per_dude'), 
         c(1200,3500,5000))
          midwest   northeast      west
 [1,] -0.26625428 -0.02752186 3.5881957
 [2,]  0.48715638  1.89169295 2.6928546
 [3,] -0.94222992  1.26065537 4.0388343
 [4,] -0.38116663  0.79572184 1.4118364
 [5,] -0.05937874  2.05459482 1.8822015
 [6,] -0.41463925  1.60668461 1.5914408
 [7,] -0.31211391  1.21093777 2.7517886
 [8,] -0.88923466  0.44917981 1.2251965
 [9,] -0.02781965 -0.24637182 2.7143103
[10,] -0.46643682  1.28944776 0.6246315
```

Comment: Ah, I always forget about mapply. This is perfect. I'm confused by this syntax though: In the function defined with d,y,b, are the "split", and then two vectors the d,y, and b arguments?

Comment: @MarcTulla `mapply` takes a function as its first argument, subsequent arguments are passed positionally to that function. So `d` is a list of dataframes created by splitting your df by region, `y` is the relevant variable in each region, and `b` is the benchmark for each region's variable.

Comment: Thomas, a quick follow up on this: In my mapply() function, what if the data I'm working on isn't "even"? Meaning, what if the splits have different numbers of observations? Say northeast had info for half the number of dates that west does, and I want to fill in the missing data with 0's. Is there any way to handle this through mapply() so that it puts together a matrix that I can line up with the dates, and fill in with 0's where needed? As it is now, it returns to me a list with elements of different length...

Comment: since this is a bit of a detailed side question, I actually started a separate thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138169/combine-list-elements-according-to-common-dataframe-value